# How can i display all the header none on a scroll event on each web page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am building a web-site that have more than one page, and i want to display the header on each page none as soon as the document gets scroll, but instead the scroll event only works on the index page.

So in this code, i created a scroll event on the window, and when this event happens it should run the scrollFunction().

```
window.onscroll= function scrollFunction(){
  var myHeader=$("header");
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 700 ){
      $(myHeader).slideUp(400);
  }
  else{$(myHeader).slideDown(800);}
}
```

// Now I expected for the function to work on all the pages because i use the jQuery to select the header, and i also put the jquery and javasript file links in all of the pages, but unfortunitely it only work on the index page.

Comment: Use devtools to confirm that the javascript file is loading properly on the other pages. If you're using a relative path to the file, it might be correct from the index page but not correct if it's starting from another page.

Comment: Do you use `AJAX` for loading the other pages? 

Comment: When you debugged, did the function get entered?   What's the value of `myHeader.length`?